# CNN model not learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm building a CNN model to classify images, however, I guess that my model is not learning because of the constant values of accuracy and loss function. See my code below:

**Building the images train, test and validation datasets**

```
import pandas as pd
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np

#Creating three datasets from the the 3 .txt files.
trainingfile = pd.read_table('data/training.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=('class', 'image'))
testingfile = pd.read_table('data/testing.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=('class', 'image'))
validationfile = pd.read_table('data/validation.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=('class', 'image'))
#Changing target variable type
trainingfile = trainingfile.replace([0, 1, 2], ['class0', 'class1', 'class2'])
testingfile = testingfile.replace([0, 1, 2], ['class0', 'class1', 'class2'])
validationfile = validationfile.replace([0, 1, 2], ['class0', 'class1', 'class2'])

#Data augmentation
datagen=ImageDataGenerator()
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( 
    #Apliquem una mica de rotació no gaire ja que generalment les fotografies estaran centrades
    rotation_range=5,
    zoom_range=0.1)

#Final datasets containing the images 
train=train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=trainingfile, directory="data/", x_col="image", y_col="class", class_mode="categorical", target_size=(256,256),color_mode='rgb',batch_size=32)
test=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=testingfile, directory="data/", x_col="image", y_col="class", class_mode="categorical", target_size=(256,256),color_mode='rgb',batch_size=32)
#No data augmentation to the validation dataset.
validation=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=validationfile, directory="data/", x_col="image", y_col="class", class_mode="categorical", target_size=(256,256),color_mode='rgb', batch_size=32)
```

**CNN model**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Activation, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from keras.constraints import maxnorm

#Creació del model
model = Sequential()
#1r bloc convolució
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 256,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#2n bloc convolució
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#3r bloc convolució
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#4t bloc convolució
model.add(Conv2D(96, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#5e bloc convolució
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))

from keras import regularizers, optimizers
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
# Compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])
# Early stopping
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1,patience=10)
```

**Training the model**

```
h=model.fit_generator(generator=train,
                      validation_data=validation,
                      epochs=50,
                      callbacks=[es])
```

**Results**

[image]

It is the first time that I use fit_generator and perhaps I'm not using it properly?

Comment: Try using  `steps_per_epoch` argument on the `fit_generator` method.

Comment: I guess there's no need since it is using by default len(train)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from the results images, you are training just for 1 epoch. This could be because the EarlyStopping is too strict. Try adding `patience=3`to the EarlyStopping callback.

```
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=3)
```

#### EDIT

Overfitting example:

[image]

Check this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/handling-overfitting-in-deep-learning-models-c760ee047c6e) to know more about how to deal with overfitting.

Comment: Buenas pedro, gracias por tu ayuda! I have modified the code to run 50 epochs and with a patience of 10 since I saw in Internet that common values are between 10-100 depending on the size of the dataset. The results seem to be better, at least, the lines are not flatted anymore. However, I guess that now I need to improve the model because I can see overfitting from epoch 1 and not a good learning curve. Do you have any suggestion? Code amended accordingly.

Comment: Please, add the new learning curve to the question so I can have an idea about what is going on. Anyway, I'll recommend you to simplify your model. Try to just with one convolutional block firstly and check how it trains. Also, you should check carefully the data. what are the values of the inputs? In which range are them? [0,1] or [0,255]. Take into account that inputs to NNs should always be standardized. Please check these things and let me know :)

Comment: the larning curve to which I refer is the loss performance. If I'm not wrong since the loss validation curve > loss train it means that there´s overfitting (see link: https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-curves-for-diagnosing-machine-learning-model-performance/). I've reduced the model as you said to just one convolutional block and it has the same behavior. In reference with the normalization of data, as far as I know, flow_from_dataframe normalizes the data automatically. My input shape are images of 256 x 256 x 3 (witdh, height, channels (RGB).

Comment: Overfitting is not exactly like this. Your learning curve seems pretty normal training, not bad at all, it goes from 0.4 to 0.9 acc. It is normal that the validation loss > training loss. Overfitting happens when your model continues to improve over training data but it gets worse with your validation data. Your model trains well until 25 epochs (more or less) then it overfits (accuracy decrease), if you are happy with that 0.9 accuracy, you can use that model for your predictions, if not you can try changing your model's architecture (like adding more dropout layers to prevent overfitting).

Comment: Understood! Thanks a lot! I´ll continue working on it then! :)